# Rails Missing Template On Production Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Before I start, I'd like to stress that I've looked for answers and I've tried to solve the issues by myself.

I have 2 types of controllers -

1. A controller with a set of methods that render JSON - works perfectly
2. A controller that actually renders HTML

This code is working perfectly on my local machine and the problem that I have with the second controller is on my production machine.

I've added 755 permissions to all my files but my file owner is the only user on my server which is "root". I've added the files to the www-data group though.

My controller is simple.

```
class AdministratorController < ApplicationController
  def login

  end
end
```

And my file is views/administrator/login.html.haml.

I'm getting an error -

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template administrator/login, application/login with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder]}. Searched in:
```

* "/var/www/sitename/app/views"
):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved. I'm not sure what exactly went wrong with the template but I began seeing a different error relating to compiled assets. I just recompiled the assets and restarted the server. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add to your Gemfile

```
gem 'haml-rails'
```

And run `bundle install`.

Comment: I've tried that. I've also tried using .html and not .html.haml. It's still showing me the same error.

Comment: No, it's still giving me a problem.